# Wordpress widget isn't working correctly

Tags: wordpress

On the link (https://truckingscout.com/test/), under widget "hundreds of job from all over the globe" there is a list of jobs, but every job is opening same link (something is wrong).

Here is a demo of the theme (https://jobify-demos.astoundify.com/classic/) so you can see how it needs to work.

Comment: This is a bit too broad. What have you tried? It's a premium theme I suggest asking the developers for support. We can't do anything without seeing the code.

Comment: Isn't that explained in the theme documentation?

Comment: Nothing is explained there since it works normally in demo. I will reach their support team, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with in your **CSS** Add following code in your active theme `style.css` and check it.

```
ul.job_listings > li:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 5px 0 0 #7dc246;
}
ul.job_listings li {
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
}
```